# Why does IDEA fail with multi-project build?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I just added a subproject to my SBT build to compile a macro. Here's the `project/Build.scala` that I added:

```
import sbt._

object DevaBuild extends Build {
    lazy val deva = Project("deva", file(".")) dependsOn macros
    lazy val macros = Project("macros", file("macros"))
}
```

It builds fine from the command line, but IntelliJ IDEA gives me this error:

```
Error:scala: Output path .../deva/project/target/idea-classes is shared between: Module 'deva-build' production, Module 'main-build' production
Output path .../deva/project/target/idea-test-classes is shared between: Module 'deva-build' tests, Module 'main-build' tests
Please configure separate output paths to proceed with the compilation.
TIP: you can use Project Artifacts to combine compiled classes if needed.
```

Comment: do you use sbt-idea plugin or internal Intellij Sbt import support (intellij-sbt plugin) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the output pathes inside Project Structure/Module/"module_name"/Paths to unique values. It's a project structure analyzing bug of sbt-idea plugin and maybe also intellij-sbt plugin.